# over_query_limit javascript v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

In my app I am trying to get a Region (city) to store in my Location model along with lngLat and address.

The thing is that for new locations it would be easy as when I would create I would do that. For old locations I wrote this bit of code

```
function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, latlngStr, callback) {
var latlng = { lat: parseFloat(latlngStr.split(',')[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr.split(',')[1]) };
var city;

geocoder.geocode({ 'location': latlng }, function (results, status) {

    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var address = results[0].address_components;
        for (var p = address.length - 1; p >= 0; p--) {
            if (address[p].types.indexOf("locality") != -1) {
                console.log(address[p].long_name);
                city = address[p].long_name;
                callback(city);
            }
        }
    }

});

}
```

And I am calling it like this

```
self.getRegion = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < self.rawLocations().length; i++) {
        var location = self.rawLocations()[i];
        setTimeout(
             geocodeLatLng(geocoder, location.systemRepresentation(), function (res) {
             }), 250);// End of setTimeOut Function - 250 being a quarter of a second. 
    }
}
```

The issue is that I get over_query_limit after 5 calls. I will store the Location it self in the database for now I would have to do this to fix the old locations.

Any headers?

Comment: Your function delays **all** the calls by 250 ms, so doesn't do anything useful. Use `i*250` for the time to delay each call 250 ms after the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google maps javascript library has a maximum calls per second as well as an hourly rate, are you trying to geocode at a rate faster than their per second rate possibly?

5 does seem low as their own documents inform users that it is 50 per second (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits)

Also have you signed up for a key and are using it? This could make a difference (if the google account is old as signed up for maps API sometime you can use the system without a key)

Comment: Alternately use https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={your address}.  this returns JSON encoded data including the lat and long.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Buckingham+Palace,London.SW1A+1AA